# Symbol lookup error only when terminal opened through a java application

Tags: java, bash, gnuplot, libraries

I wrote a bash script. As an example, a really easy on:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot -e "set terminal pdf; set output'/tmp/test.pdf'; plot [-10:10] sin(x);"
```

This script shall have the name test.sh .
I can execute this script through my shell and the test.pdf is created. Should I execute this script through a Java application that calls this script through a ProcessBuilder, no pdf is created. The script is accessed and other programs like gedit are opened. Awk etc works. There just seems to be a problem with gnuplot.

Does anyone know why that is and how I could fix this?

The java code is:

```
String command = "/tmp/test.sh";

try {
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c",command);
  pb.start();
}catch (IOExeption e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace()
}
```

--- Update ---

There seems to be another issue. Thanks to ccarton and muzido the gnuplot script is executed if the java-jar file is executed through the shell. If I embed it into another shell that looks simplified like this execute_jar.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar test.jar
```

And this execute_jar.sh is executed by another java application that only can execute shell scripts and that I can't modify.
Is there a problem with this parent application? Or is a workaround possible?
The gnuplot script has to be executed through my test.jar because other parameters are generated in the jar and given to the script.

--- Update 2 ---

So I have been searching some more and to test a little bit I changed the test.jar so that it doesn't execute the test.sh but just opens a shell with "xterm". Here I then manually type in the script and I get the error `"gnuplot: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libQtSvg.so.4: undefined symbol"`
Any ideas?

--- Update 3 ---

I tought it my be a Library problem because the "/usr/lib64/libQtSvg.so.4" exists. So I tried `export LD_LIBRARY:$LD_LIBRARY:/usr/lib64` but still the same error.

--- Update 4 ---

I changed the title

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, please [edit] your question to include your java source code for executing this script.

Comment: Nothing appears when using "rpm -qa|grep libQt", neither in the terminal opened by the jar nor the "normal" one, but the file exists in the said path where the symbol couldn't be looked up (at  /usr/lib/libQtSvg.so.4)

Answer (score 0):

add to " end of line.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot -e "set terminal pdf; set output'/tmp/test.pdf'; plot [-10:10] sin(x);"
```

to executable file;

```
chmod +x /tmp/test.sh
```

this is java code; when run this, test.pdf is created in /tmp/.

```
public class RunShellScript
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
           String command = "/tmp/test.sh";
            try{
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c",command);
                    Process p = pb.start();
                    p.waitFor();
                    int shellExitStatus = p.exitValue();
                    System.out.println(shellExitStatus);
            }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

when run this, what is the java console output?

Comment: I got the shellExitStatus 0 and the pdf file was created if I execute it through eclipse. If I export it as a jar and execute it in the shell with "java -jar file.jar" no pdf is created...

Comment: when run "java -cp file.jar RunShellScript", this also created pdf in my env.

Comment: I'm on CentOS and when using your command it tells me "Could not find or load RunShellScript". I'm using a Bash Shell.

Comment: I dont have a manifest, could you change RunShellScript to full.package.name.YourClassName.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad! Thank you again for you answer. Still the same problem as I updated in my first question post. If I execute the jar in the shell it works but if it's embedded in shell script and this shell script executed by a parent java it doesn't work :(

Comment: what is gnuplot version and java version?

Comment: I have gnuplot 5.0 and java SE 1.7, I just tested some more and when executing the execute_jar.sh through the parent java app I get the error: "gnuplot: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libQtSvg.so.4: undefined symbol"

Comment: The libQtSvg.so.4 is already in /usr/lib64/ . Sorry I'm not too deep into linux.

Comment: could you provided rpm -qa | grep -i libqt

Comment: Still nothing when using rpm -qa | grep -i libqt

Answer (score 0):

Scripts are not actually executables. The shebang (`#!`) is interpreted by your command shell. ProcessBuilder won't do that. To run this from Java you need to execute /bin/bash directly and pass this script as a command line argument.

Example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "test.sh");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick anwer! How do I execute /bin/bash directly and pass this script as a command line argument?

Comment: There seems to be another Problem: If I execute the jar through the console with "java -jar ..." there is no problem. If I write the jar execution in a bash script and launch this script through another java application gnuplot is not executed. Could the problem be with the first java app?